# how to let dropdown menu align-right?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i used bootstrap navbar,and a dropdown menu at right of the navbar,when run on big page,the dropdown menu can popup at right,it`s ok,but when i change the window size,the dropdown menu popup at left of the page?why?how to let it popup at right of the window always?

these are css code:

```
       <style>
        .navbar-header, .navbar-brand {
            float: left !important;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle {
            float: right !important;
        }

        .navbar-right:last-child {
            margin-right: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 8px !important;
        }

    </style>
```

these are html code：

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-label="Left Align">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

how to let it popup at right of the window always? thanks,thanks.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or bootply so we can see code in action

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taobataoma/2w2ayyg4/
here is the fiddle demo,you can see the popup menu at left of the iframe window,when you split the iframe window to big big big,the popup menu be going right of the iframe window,i want it always popup at right of iframe window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css and it should fix the problem:

What it's doing is overwriting the `left` bootstrap setting and replacing it with `right: 0`

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  right:0;
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: i test it in chrome ,it`s very ok, in safiri,the popup menu width is the window width, how fix it?

Comment: please see updated code and check again - change `left: unset` to `left: auto` - I didn't realize it was not well supported

Comment: Welcome, happy to and glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to keep track of the float tag, that is fine but try to think about the position tag in your code and set the position to relative. Here is the code:

```css
      <style>
        .navbar-header, .navbar-brand {
            float: left !important;
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle {
            float: right !important;
            position: relative;
        }

        .navbar-right:last-child {
            margin-right: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 8px !important;
            position: relative;
        }

    </style>
```

Try to fiddle with the position tag a bit and you should get your result ;)

Comment: I used you css code,when i change the browser window to smaller size, the popup menu at left the window,but i want it to be at right of the window,when i change the window to big size,the popup menu at the right of window,this time ,it`s ok

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taobataoma/2w2ayyg4/
here is the fiddle demo,you can see the popup menu at left of the iframe window,when you split the iframe window to big big big,the popup menu be going right of the iframe window,i want it always popup at right of iframe window

Answer (score 0):

Appending the line `.dropdown-menu { margin-left: 52.5vw; }` to your css will force the dropdown menu to be at the right of the screen, always.